# Bulk update in SQL stored procedure with select and join in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012-web

I have two tables in SQL Server 2012 with the following structure:

```
customer  
- internalId  
- listingStatus  
- inactive  
membership  
- custIntneralId  
- regDate
```

Here is the SELECT statement I am using:

```
USE [dbOne]  
SELECT DISTINCT(t1.internalId)  
FROM customer AS t1  
INNER JOIN membership AS t2 ON t1.internalId = t2.custInternalId  
WHERE t1.internalId = t2.custInternalId  
AND t1.inactive = 0  
AND t1.listingStatus = ''
```

And here is the UPDATE statement if I were to use a loop to insert row by row:

```
UPDATE customer SET listingStatus = '6' WHERE internalId=custInternalId
```

Since I want to do bulk updates rather than row by row, I am trying to write a stored procedure I can trigger to do a bulk update. I have tried several different ways to write it, but have been unable to get them to work. Here is an example of one of the stored procedures I have tried:

```
USE [dbOne]  
UPDATE customer  
SET customer.listingStatus = '6'  
FROM customer AS t1  
INNER JOIN membership AS t2 ON t1.internalId = t2.custInternalId  
WHERE t1.internalId = t2.custInternalId  
AND t1.inactive = 0  
AND t1.listingStatus = ''
```

I've also tried putting the select statement inside the WHERE clause of the UPDATE statement, that didn't work. I can't see what I'm missing, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server you can specify the table alias as the update target.  You don't have to prefix column names, since you can only update one table with a single update:

```
UPDATE  t1
SET     custentity_iahp_listing_status = '6'  
FROM    customer AS t1
JOIN    MembershipPurchaseHistory AS t2
ON      t1.internalId = t2.custInternalId  
WHERE   t1.inactive = 0
        AND t1.custentity_iahp_listing_status = ''
```

No need to repeat the `ON` clause in the `WHERE` clause, that's been taken care of.

Note that in your `SELECT` query you join the `membership` table, but your update joins the `MembershipPurchaseHistory` table.  That might give different results.